# Getting a node list by querySelectorAll()

Tags: polymer, web-component, shadow-dom, lit-element

Given the following sample code:

```js
import { LitElement, html, css } from 'lit-element';

class ItemsDisplay extends LitElement {

    static get styles() {...}
    static get properties {...}

    constructor () {
        super();
        ...
    }

    render {
        return html`
            ${this.items.map((item, index, array) => html`
                <div class="name">
                    ...
                </div>
            `)}        
        `;
    }
}
```

What is the appropriate way to select all nodes with class "name"?

I have tried the following ways, but **failed**; all times `nodesList` was `undefined`:

- Inside `constructor`:

```js
  this.nodesList = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll(".name");
```

- Using:

```js
  firstUpdated(changedProperties) {
      return this.nodesList = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll(".name");
  }
```

- Inside a custom function:

```js
  getNodesList() {
      let nodesList = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll(".name");
      ...
  }
```

I have also tried with:

```js
connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    return this.nodesList = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll(".name");
}
```

Looking forward reading the solution.

Tia

Comment: It will depend on when you call it. You have to make sure that the DOM has be added to `shadowRoot` before the `querySelectorAll` will work. Can you add an example of when you are trying to call it?

Comment: I am trying to call it from `constructor` as `this.getNodesList()`, a function which is placed after `render`. I thought that `lit-element` takes care all necessary work in order a new `element` to be added to the DOM automatically and/or shadowDOM to be added to the shadowRoot!. What do I miss? How can I check within 'lit-element` that shadowRoot is ready for parsing? Tia

Comment: I have not used lit, but you may need to place your call in a `setTimeout` to allow the browser time to do the actual rendering before the content is really available

Comment: You're not going to be able to query the DOM in the `constructor` and even in `connectedCallback` DOM nodes probably aren't going to be ready yet. What are are you trying to do with the elements and why do you need to query them so early?

Comment: @Intervalia Tnks for your help. Please also have a look at this [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54872823/how-to-check-the-initial-render-state-not-the-update-state-of-a-component-in). `setTimeout` will work but it is not the way which will satisfy me! It is an ultimate solution but not an elegant one. A `promise` could be ideal.

Comment: @abraham Tnks for your help. Please also have a look at this [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54872823/how-to-check-the-initial-render-state-not-the-update-state-of-a-component-in). When is it **early** or **late**?! Both have to do with the moment of render completion, don't they? I just want to change some attributes of them.

Comment: @Intervalia `setTimeout` does work.

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't try to access DOM node in the constructor, because they won't be available yet.

The best place to query DOM nodes is the `firstUpdated()` lifecycle callback, which is called after the first time your element's DOM has been updated. You also don't need to return it from `firstUpdated`, you can just do something like:

```js
  firstUpdated(changedProperties) {
    // Store a reference to the form element for easy access
    this.$someNode = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('div');
```

You can see some examples of this over at: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/open-wc-lit-demos?file=02-intermediate%2F05-querying-dom.js

https://stackblitz.com/edit/open-wc-lit-demos?file=02-intermediate%2F01-first-updated.js

Additionally, if you're using TypeScript, you can use the `query` decorator:

```
@query('div')
myDiv;
```

More info: https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element/blob/master/src/test/lib/decorators_test.ts#L326

Comment: Thnks for your response.I have seen all these examples. I have also used `firstUpdated()` but failed. `changedProperties` is an optional argument in the function or not? In `01-first-updated.js` example, the argument is present but never used/declared. I still read the doc and see the examples over and over again!